# How to group 2d spatial grid data based on their elevation using clustering: clusters have to be contiguous

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

[image]

I have 2d gridded data that I want to group based on elevation, but the clusters have to be continuous and have a minimum number of data in the (4). A visual representation of the clustering would look like that:

Thanks!

[image: gridded data with clusters]

Comment: Clustering finds things that are contiguous in whatever features you give the algorithm. So give it x and y, in addition to z (elevation). But choose the algo carefully because they all have their foibles, eg k-means wants roughly equal-sized clusters. Check this out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit - Matt makes a good point about K-Means... added Spectral Clustering too.

Because each point has no label, just a position in space, you could treat it as an unsupervised learning problem and use K-Means to create clusters.

The clusters would be contiguous because every point on your 2D grid would be assigned to one and only one cluster. If you want the borders to only be vertical and horizontal lines like in your drawings you could take the final predictions of K-Means, and use them as labels in a Decision Tree where the only features are x and y.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

grid_size = 100
grid = [[row, column, 75 * math.sin(row/25) * math.sin(column/25)] for row in range(grid_size) for column in range(grid_size)]
elevations = pd.DataFrame(grid, columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'])

clf = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0, n_init=10)
clf.fit(elevations)
centers = clf.cluster_centers_

predictions = clf.predict(elevations)
predictions = predictions.reshape(grid_size, grid_size)

plt.imshow(predictions, interpolation='nearest',
           extent=(0, grid_size, 0, grid_size),
           cmap=plt.cm.Pastel1,
           aspect='auto', origin='lower')

plt.scatter(elevations['x'], elevations['y'], c = elevations['z'], s=1)

plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1],
            marker='x', s=100, linewidths=3,
            color='w', zorder=10)
```

[image: Initial Elevation Map]
[image: K Means]
[image: Spectral]